# OledbDataReader is not retrieving all the columns

Tags: c#

I'm have little problem in retrieving the data from a table here's the code: if the column in the db table is empty then the exception is thrown...

```
                string cmdText = "select member_id,disp_id,mobile_no,tm,pm,lm,due_date from Recharge";
                string UpdateStatus = "",hepUpdateStatus="";
                OleDbCommand cmdFinalUpdate = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn);
                OleDbDataReader updateReader = cmdFinalUpdate.ExecuteReader();
                if (!updateReader.HasRows) // this condition is creating problem
                    MessageBox.Show("No Data Pending For Updation");
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (updateReader.Read())
                        {
                            Program.MemberID = Convert.ToInt64(updateReader.GetInt32(0));
                            Program.DispID = updateReader.GetString(1);
                            Program.Mobile = updateReader.GetString(2);
                            Program.Tm = updateReader.GetString(3);
                            Program.Pm = updateReader.GetString(4);
                            Program.Remarks = updateReader.GetString(5);
                            Program.DueDate = updateReader.GetString(6);
                       }
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                    finally
                    {
                        updateReader.Close();
                    }

                  }
```

The Problem is, it is giving error on Forth Column  i.e `Program.Pm = updateReader.GetString(4);` the error is `specified cast is not valid` (actually after the 3rd column it is giving exception) but im pretty sure that casting is not the issue, coz When i remove the `if condtion` at the top i.e `if (!updateReader.HasRows)` then the code works perfectly fine, i wanna know what is the problem with that reader if m checkin' that reader has rows or not ?

Comment: I can see you are using OleDb. What is the backend database ?

Comment: @controlbreak:its MSAccess Db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the GetString() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring.aspx):

> No conversions are performed; therefore the data retrieved must already be a string.

Looks like `Recharge.pm` is not a string or contains a NULL value.

Comment: @Frederic: ofcourse `Recharge.pm` is a string, and i mention'd up there that if i remove that `if condition` (commented) then the code is working fine...

Comment: @Orsol: you mean to say the column `updateReader.GetString(4)` this is null  or the variable Recharge.pm is null ?

Comment: @Orsol: the Recharge.pm is not null and the column 'updateReader.GetString(4);' is also not null..ne hw i already said dear, the code runs just fine if i remove thjs condition `if (!updateReader.HasRows)`.

Comment: Does the code still run fine if you call `updateReader.HasRows` outside of the `if` statement?

Comment: @Frederic: yeah it is still throwin' exception, but you know when i removed the data from that `pm` column manually from access db, so now 'pm' field is empty then it is giving exception.. when i enter some data into it then the code is working fine.. what could be the problem ?

Comment: You should call [IsDbNull()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.isdbnull.aspx) and only proceed to `GetString()` if it returns `false`.

Comment: so i need to specify `IsDbNull()` for every column ?

Comment: For every nullable column, yes.